# Chromium sandbox error from the command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, security, chromium

When I issue the `chromium-browser` command line in Ubuntu 18.04 I get some weird output

```
user@computer:~$ chromium-browser
Using PPAPI flash.
[15146:15146:0309/115259.140796:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(364)] 
InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

How do I overcome the Chrome sandbox error shown above?